# Emulate a bluetooth mouse

Tags: bluetooth, hid

Is it possible for my computer to pretend it is a bluetooth mouse, so another device can connect to it?

An android device allow its mouse to be controlled by bluetooth without rooting it, and my computer have bluetooth, so if I could get them to speek the same language/protocol, I could send mouse-commands from the computer to the android.

Is it possible, or am I just dreaming? :-)

Answer (score 8):

I know a project called [Master Control](https://pyra-handheld.com/boards/threads/wip-master-control-testers-needed.72081/) which did exactly that: a program would read events from local `/dev/input` sources and resend those events either via Bluetooth HID profile or via USB using `gadgetfs`. This could effectively emulate either BT or USB mouse, keyboard or joystick.

The original project was built for ARM, and I'm not sure if the author (Roger Zoellner) has ever released the sources. You may want to ping him about it, so you don't have to re-implement everything from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's possible. For example, [hidclient](http://anselm.hoffmeister.be/computer/hidclient/index.html.en) allows you to use a Linux PC as a bluetooth keyboard and mouse for another device.

Comment: My tablet can see the computer, and its has "Audio" and "Input", but if I try to use it as "Input", it just say its unable to connect :-( Any ide how to find out why?

Comment: What exactly have you done (step-by-step description of commands used)? Permissions correct for the user that runs the programs? How exactly did you try to use it as input, and what's the exact error message? What does the syslog say?

Comment: any luck getting hidclient to work on ubuntu 16.04? I tried the readme here https://github.com/benizi/hidclient

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are dreaming. I think that this can be done using a programming language like Python , C , etc. 
For example in Python with a quick search i found this tutorial based on PyBluez: https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c212.html

By the way, May be already available apps could fit your needs.
I had been using AirDroid apps a couple of years ago and i was very happy with it since i could browse my android phone by my PC using just WiFi (not cable , not BlueTooth).

PS: AirDroid does not require root access to your phone, you can use your PC Keyboard and mouse and is still available in google play. Unfortunately i can not tell for sure if AirDroid can work with BT or if there are AirDroid BT apps.

Comment: AirDroid sounds nice, should test it, all apps i found required rooted devices

Comment: AirDroid runs without root , i have tried this thing and i can confirm it! But it is Wifi, not bluetooth.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: To send mouse-events, I had to use Chrome (not firefox), and I needed to connect a USB-cabel.

Comment: I'm surprised that this requires a usb cable to operate... even today, their app claim that works remotelly based on wifi.

Comment: Maybe works without a usb-kabel in the windows-desktop-app, but as I'm using kubuntu, I had to use chrome, and it asked me to connect the usb-cabel.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to control an android device from your computer, you might want to look into [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy). It mirrors your device screen to your pc and allows you to interact with your phone using your mouse and keyboard. It also allows you to do things like rotate your phone and turning your phone screen off.